# Is there a name for "reverse" triangular matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

Take the following matrix

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6\end{bmatrix}$$

I was wondering if there was a term for these types of "reverse triangular" matrices, and if they hold any properties. I assume they will not enjoy nearly as many properties as ordinary triangular matrices.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227345/name-for-diagonals-of-a-matrix – is it a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218093/skew-triangular-matrices-and-their-properties ?

Comment: Yes, thank you for sharing this.

Comment: I think they're just called "upper triangular" and "lower triangular".